# Where is webforms template info stored in the database

Tags: database, webforms

I'm using webforms in Drupal 8.  I have migrated an old database over but need to overwrite the correct webforms table to restore a webform template I created on a previous site.  Can you tell me which table in the database the template webform fields are stored please?

Comment: Webforms and templates are config entities. You can export and import config from one website to another. @see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management

Comment: I can't access the old site.  I only have the database.

Comment: All configuration data for D8 is in the 'config' table